# Incorrect Syntax - With Statement

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have a query which truncates and inserts data from the stored procedure table. However, I am not able to create stored procedure since I have `;With` statement after `INSERT INTO` table. The query is below. Can someone please help me?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [BC].[TestStoredProc]
AS
BEGIN TRY
    set nocount on
    set xact_abort on
    set ansi_warnings off
    set arithabort off
    set arithignore on

BEGIN TRAN
    TRUNCATE TABLE [S].[sample]

    INSERT INTO [S].[sample] ([ColumnID])
        ;WITH P AS 
        (
            SELECT a, b, c
            FROM testtable
        )
    
    SELECT PC.columnID
    FROM ABC RC
    LEFT JOIN BCD CC ON RC.BCD = CC.BCD
    LEFT JOIN P PC ON RC.fldClientId = PC.fldPersonID
    
    
    COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF (XACT_STATE() <> 0)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END;

    THROW;
END CATCH

RETURN 0
```

Error:

> Procedure [BC].[TestStorproc], Line 40 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near ';'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that the CTE is defined incorrectly, you must define them before your query, that is why the `;` prefix hack works, a CTE can only be the *FIRST* statement in a query.

Once you resolve that though, next error, is that your CTE does not have a field called `fldClientId`, it only has columns `a`,`b`,`c`...

> I suspect you have over-simplified your example, for the rest of this solution lets assume that `P` has a `fldClientId`

Move the CTE outside of the `INSERT`:

```
;With P as (
    SELECT a, b, c, fldClientId
    FROM testtable
)
INSERT INTO [S].[sample]([ColumnID])
SELECT PC.columnID
FROM ABC RC
LEFT JOIN BCD CC on RC.BCD = CC.BCD
LEFT JOIN P PC on RC.fldClientId = PC.fldPersonID
```

However, your CTE is so simple, it's just a column projection, and you're not re-using it in the query, so you can transpose that inline:

```
INSERT INTO [S].[sample]([ColumnID])
SELECT PC.columnID
FROM ABC RC
LEFT JOIN BCD CC on RC.BCD = CC.BCD
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT a, b, c, fldClientId 
    FROM testtable
) AS PC on RC.fldClientId = PC.fldPersonID
```

Which again can be further simplified to:

```
INSERT INTO [S].[sample]([ColumnID])
SELECT PC.columnID
FROM ABC RC
LEFT JOIN BCD CC on RC.BCD = CC.BCD
LEFT JOIN testtable AS PC on RC.fldClientId = PC.fldPersonID
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not an exact answer, but you should be able to just inline the CTE here.  Actually, I don't see any filtering or aggregation in your CTE, so maybe just directly join to the table:

```sql
INSERT INTO [S].[sample] ([ColumnID])

SELECT PC.columnID
FROM ABC RC
LEFT JOIN BCD CC ON RC.BCD = CC.BCD
LEFT JOIN testtable PC ON RC.fldClientId = PC.fldPersonID
```

Comment: This answer was posted substantially before the answer you accepted.